# What is the use of templates in cpp while the same task can be performed with function overloading?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, overloading

Why C++ provides templates ? Same task can be done using function overloading. Is there any advantage of using templates over function overloading?

Comment: How you would write `std::swap` with function overloading, for example?

Comment: "Same task can be done using function overloading". No it cannot.

Comment: how would you write std::vector with function overloading?

Comment: Everything can be done by writing machine code directly, so why do we have programming languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Same task can be done using function overloading

**No, it can't**

How do you write overloads for types that don't exist yet?

How do you write overloads for types that don't have a name?

How does *function* overloading help you write multiple similar *classes*?

**And you'd still want templates**

Why would you write the same implementation dozens (hundreds, millions?) of times?

Comment: Is there any other advantage except the one you mentioned

Comment: Well there are probably loads more things that function overloading can't do nicely, the first list isn't exhaustive. But the main point is that *not writing code* is by far and away the most important difference

Comment: @Proton are they not enough advantages already?

Comment: if you have a class / function that operates on one arithmetic type but needs to handle every option, you will need to copy & paste it to have 10 overloads for every `int`, `float`, `double`, `uint8_t` etc version. now you change some code in their because there was a bug, and you have to apply that change to every overload. I don't think I have to explain why this will slow down debugging and development in general by a lot

Comment: @StackDanny `std::sort` is more compelling than arithmetic. I don't want to have to correctly transfer state of the art sort implementation to every combination of container and ordering that my programs use, and I don't want to have to send trade secrets to (multiple) compiler vendors for them to do it.

Comment: sure, generic implementations become impossible. I think the OP doesn't do any generic stuff, so I wanted to show him how overloading a few types can work temporary, but immediately will land you in a nightmare situation.

Comment: OP should be *using* existing generic definitions